# How to set start screen tiles' language in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, language, start-screen

I've installed English Windows 8 x64 on my notebook and selected Slovenian as locale during installation. Like so:

[image]

The problem I'm having now is that my tiles on start screen display in Slovenian even though my installation is English. I've also edited languages, adding English (British) on the list and putting it on top of Slovenian, but tiles still use Slovenian.

[image]

All previous Windows versions were able to have English UI with a particular locale for input, time, dates, currency etc.

#### How can I do the same in Windows 8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open the **Clock, Language, and Region** section from the Control Panel:

   [image]
2. Open the **Language** panel:

   [image]
3. Here we can see the issue:

   [image]

   To resolve your language conflict, add a new language [image]
4. Open the **English** language catalogue:

   [image]
5. Pick whatever English language you prefer and **Add** it:

   [image]
6. Open the **Options** for your newly added language and add a new input method:

   [image]
   [image]
7. Pick the **Slovenian** keyboard layout, add it and **save** your setup:

   [image]
8. You can now **Move up** your new configuration and **Remove** the old one.

   [image]

   Your date, number and time formats should still be set to Slovenian:

   [image]
9. **Restart** Windows.
10. Success

    [image]

Comment: -1 for a very detailed answer :P

Comment: What i figured out yesterday as well, nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answers to your problem may lie in the Windows 8 language Advanced settings and Region settings. Here's a way to change input:

Press the Windows logo key + space. While holding down the windows logo key, press space until the input you want is highlighted. That input will now be in effect.

Here's a way to change currency, time, dates, etc:

Go to Control Panel, and click the **Change date, time, or number formats**.
On the Formats tab of the Region window, select the country whose formats you want on your computer.
Click the **Additional setting** button on the lower, left corner (above OK) of the Region window.
You can select number, currency, time, date, and ather tabs to choose options.

Going back to the Region window, select the Location tab. 
Select United States (or United Kingdom) from the drop down.
Click **Apply**.
Click **OK**.

On the Region window, select the **Administrative** tab.
Click the **Copy Settings** button.
If you are satisfied with the settings for **Current User**, select the check box next to **Welcome screen and system accounts**, which will apply your language choices to more areas of the interface.

Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Oliver Salzburg's answer](https://superuser.com/a/494659) is very good and complete, but it did not solve the issue for Belgian/Dutch language and keyboard.

I wanted the tiles in English and the keyboard in "Belgium (Period)". After reading this post and some rebooting, trial and error I found my solution.

My settings were these:

[image: image description here]

1. First language: English (UK)

   - Keyboard: English (UK)
2. Second language: Dutch (Belgium)

   - Keyboard: Belgian (Period)
   - Date/time: Dutch (Belgium)