# How to change the language of Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set start screen tiles' language in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/486753/how-to-set-start-screen-tiles-language-in-windows-8)

Just upgraded to Windows 8 (from Windows 7) and I noticed that some apps from store are displayed in my native language (which is Romanian).

The thing is that the only settings that are related to Romania are the keyboard and the timezone. The UI is in English, the Locale is set to United States.

There is a way of preventing this and make all apps to be displayed in English?

Comment: There is a setting that says something like "make apps in my languages easier to find", maybe that's enabled?

Comment: @Louis: thanks, but the thing is i DON'T want apps in my language. Basically because the translation is poor and some terms are translated wrong. After 12years+ with English IT it's pretty damn hard to change to another language :)

Comment: @lonutstaicu I was going to suggest turning it off.

Comment: Ah! Was already Off :)

Comment: just to be clear are these apps that could also be displayed in English but for whatever reason are showing up in Romanian? I'm also wondering if you're in Romania and the Store is using your location to decide to show Romanian apps? If that's the case, I'm curious if enabling the setting would help.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. E.g. Teamviewer have an English version, but it's displayed in Romanian. I really hope it's not based on Store location!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you choose multi language while installing Windows 8 and not just English?

Try checking with *Control Panel » Clock, Language, Region » Language*. Try and set English as default or deleting the other languages.

Comment: Damn man, you are right! I totally ignored that because i thought it's strictly related to keyboard layout. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your Welcome :)