# Windows keeps trying to install apps with my native language

Tags: windows-10, language, installer

Every time I install a software it's trying to install it in  my native language, when available (not English), so I always have to take care to change it to English and then proceed with the installer. How can I have it to English by default? My Windows 10 Education is in English, only my keyboard is set to Romanian. Thanks!

Comment: Install the Romanian language pack if its available.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/486753/how-to-set-start-screen-tiles-language-in-windows-8) is a related question, and although it was asked with regards to Windows 8, the answer applies to Windows 10 also.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/948660/change-windows-7-8-10-system-language-welcome-screen-login-etc) is how you change the interface language of Windows if you are wondering.

Answer (score -2):

Change your location from Control Panel > Region and Language > Location tab

Comment: What it should be good for?